# rotate html body background

Tags: css, html

Hope someone can tell me if this is possible

I have a website in opencart the background is a "earth" picture, I want to animate it by letting it rotate on its z axis so it turns clockwise.

```
body {
 background:url('../image/bg.jpg') repeat;
color: #000000;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

this is the css sets the background, I have located this piece but I see I cant refer to a background property? Not sure, but this is what I basically want the background property of the body to do.

```
.image {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   width: 120px;
   height: 120px;
   margin:-60px 0 0 -60px;
   -webkit-animation:spin 8s linear infinite;
   -moz-animation:spin 8s linear infinite;
   animation:spin 8s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }

@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }

@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
ransform:rotate(360deg);    }     }
```

Is this in anyway possible to rotate the background image of a html page?

Comment: Have you tried setting `transform: rotate(0deg);` in the .image class to start with? So then it has two values to animate between?

Comment: It rotates the image if i have a <img src.. but the i want to apply something similar to the background image of the body tag, so the .image css is not correct so there must be a way of telling the css that the body background-image needs to rotate?

Comment: You cannot rotate a background-image. You might be able to rotate an element (not the body) but an absolutely positioned div...that you could rotate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we have said, you CAN'T rotate a bg image. What you can do is add the image into your HTML, position it absolutely, and rotate that

[**JSFiddle for inline image**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/K8XX2/1/)

As an alternative you could use a pseudo-element which would remove the image from the HTML completely and place it back in the CSS where it belongs

[**JSFiddle for Pseudo-element**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/K8XX2/2/)

```
body {
    position:relative;
}

body:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    margin:-60px 0 0 -60px;
    background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/300/300);
    -webkit-animation:spin 8s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 8s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 8s linear infinite;
    opacity:0.5;
    border-radius:50%;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { transform:rotate(360deg);    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to apply your `transform` to rotate the background-image: it can only be applied to the whole DOM element. Your best bet will be - rather than applying the background to the `body` tag - to include the image itself in your markup.

You will then be apply to use positioning and z-index to visually get the image in the right place, and as it's in the markup you can apply the `transform` on that element.

What I've described above is [exactly what your example code achieves](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/K8XX2/) (I haven't touched the CSS in that fiddle), so I'm slightly confused as to what your issue is.

Comment: do you think I will get it rotating(animate) as per code above for the image? if yes if you could really please give me the smalles example of what to do, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Check out the link in my answer - is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I have checked that part out, for me its brilliant code, But I need this to rotate the background-image, yours works brilliantly if I have a <img tag, but I dont as the css sets the background tag for the body, and I want to let it look if this world is spinning clockwise in the background, Thanks for your time. "body background="x.jpg"> I need that picture to spin, (sorry if my explanation sound bad - but thank you for listening)

Comment: As we have said, you CAN'T rotate a bg image. What you can do is add the image into your HTML, position it absolutely, and rotate that. See: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/K8XX2/1/